# Example of a set being subset of its power set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Could anyone please give an enlightening example of such set pls? Different from trivial one like empty set or set of empty set please? Thanks in advance

Comment: This depends of course on the set you are considering. However, at least the empty set and the set itself are in the power set. Maybe you should consider a particular example.

Comment: These are usually called *transitive* sets and have also been called *full* sets. [See here.](http://oeis.org/A001192)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let’s see what conditions an example must satisfy.

Suppose that $x\subseteq\wp(x)$, and suppose further that $x\ne\varnothing$. The [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity), which is one of the standard axioms of set theory, says that there is an element $y\in x$ such that $y\cap x=\varnothing$. Since $y\in x\subseteq\wp(x)$, we know that $y\in\wp(x)$ and hence that $y\subseteq x$. Suppose that $y\ne\varnothing$, and let $z\in y$. Then $z\in x$, so $z\in x\cap y=\varnothing$, which is obviously impossible, so $y$ must be empty. In other words, if $\varnothing\ne x\subseteq\wp(x)$, it must be the case that $\varnothing\in x$.

Now let $y=x\setminus\{\varnothing\}$. If $y=\varnothing$, then $x=\{\varnothing\}$, $\wp(x)=\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\big\}$, and it’s true that $x\subseteq\wp(x)$.

If $y\ne\varnothing$, then the result of the previous paragraph shows that $y\nsubseteq\wp(y)$, since $\varnothing\ne y$. That is, there is a $z\in y$ such that $z\nsubseteq y$. Since $z\in y\subseteq x$, clearly $z\in x\subseteq\wp(x)$, so $z\subseteq x=y\cup\{\varnothing\}$. This means that $\varnothing\in z$. Let’s try to use this in the simplest possible way to find another example: we’ll set $z=\{\varnothing\}$, $y=\{z\}=\big\{\{\varnothing\}\big\}$, and $x=y\cup\{\varnothing\}=\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\big\}$. Does it work? Yes:

$$\wp(x)=\left\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\big\{\{\varnothing\}\big\},\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\big\}\right\}\supseteq\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\big\}=x\;.$$

The first example was $x_1=\{\varnothing\}$, and the second was $x_2=\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\big\}=\wp(x_1)$. What if we try

$$x_3=\wp(x_2)=\left\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\},\big\{\{\varnothing\}\big\},\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\big\}\right\}\;?$$

Then you can check by direct computation that indeed $x_3\subseteq\wp(x_3)$.

In fact, we can prove the following

> **Proposition.** If $x\subseteq\wp(x)$, then $\wp(x)\subseteq\wp\big(\wp(x)\big)$. In other words, if $x$ is an example, so is $\wp(x)$.
>
> **Proof.** Suppose that $x\subseteq\wp(x)$. Let $y\in\wp(x)$; we want to show that $y\in\wp\big(\wp(x)\big)$. That is, we have $y\subseteq x$, and we want to show that $y\subseteq\wp(x)$. But this is easy: if $z\in y$, then $z\in x$, since $y\subseteq x$, so $z\in\wp(x)$. Thus, every element of $y$ is an element of $\wp(x)$, i.e., $y\subseteq\wp(x)$. $\dashv$

Now you can make bigger and bigger examples by starting with the trivial one, $x_0=\varnothing$, and repeatedly taking power sets to get $x_1=\{\varnothing\}$, $x_2=\wp(x_1)=\big\{\varnothing,\{\varnothing\}\big\}$, and so on. The first two are your trivial examples, but the rest are increasingly complicated. In fact, for $n\ge 1$ we have $|x_n|=2^{n-1}$.